# AWS SDK PHP S3Client putObject get stuck

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a script which generate lot of XML files, and upload them one by one into S3 with this basic code:

```
    $this->awsFactory->getS3Client()->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'Body'   => $xml,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
        '@http' => [
            'progress' => function ($expectedDl, $dl, $expectedUl, $ul) {
                printf(
                    "%s/%s uploaded.\n",
                    $ul,
                    $expectedUl
                );
            }
        ]
    ]);
```

(I added the callback because of my problem)

Sometime, randomly, the upload is stuck, and never timeout. Sometime it restart after fiew minutes, sometime not.
It can happen after 60 files, or after more that 150 files, totally random

Here the callback example:

```
0/0 uploaded.
0/2128256 uploaded.
16384/2128256 uploaded.
16384/2128256 uploaded.
32768/2128256 uploaded.
32768/2128256 uploaded.
49152/2128256 uploaded.
// ...
// (it start normally)
// And at a moment, the upload stop send datas
// ...
1048576/2128256 uploaded.
1064960/2128256 uploaded.
1064960/2128256 uploaded.
1081344/2128256 uploaded.
1081344/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
1097728/2128256 uploaded.
// ...
```

it stuck at 1097728/2128256, and I got thousands of same lines

Any ideas of what happen?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: what's the full code? how do you generate the xml? could it be memory issue due to large $xml variables not being freed?

Comment: I monitor the memory, it's only at 63.1Mb. The $xml string lenght is approximativly 2100000 characters each one.

Comment: The full code is a Symfony Application, xml is rendered with Twig

Comment: have you tried using promise? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_basic-usage.html